# copy a column in a .csv file to another using batch

Tags: batch-file, csv, copy

I have a file that has

```
Class,section,name
Math,02,Scott
```

What I need is a .csv that copies a column so it looks like below

```
Class,section,name,class
Math,02,Scott,Math
```

I am looking to do this using batch file commands.  Any suggestions?  I know how to do basic copy commands, and tried downloading python but was having trouble getting it to work

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "tokens=1-3delims=," %%a IN (q22334682.txt) DO (
 ECHO(%%a,%%b,%%c,%%a
)
)>new.csv

GOTO :EOF
```

-Assuming that the case of the `class` header on the generated column in the file should match that in column 1.

I used a file named `q22334682.txt` for my testing, putting the result in `new.csv`.