# batch script copy cells from csv file to another csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have two csv files: one with only two cells (1x2) in two columns and another one with 256x1024 cells and the plan is to copy the two cells of the 1st csv to the 2nd csv file therefore putting them in the first two columns of the 2nd csv and shifting the 256x1024 cells by two columns to the right, I found this [copy a column in a .csv file to another using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334682/copy-a-column-in-a-csv-file-to-another-using-batch) as an example but I am not sure how to adjust it for my case, any suggestion/explanation? The delimiter is ;

Comment: is this possible with C programming maybe???

Comment: What about your CSVs: contain a header line? which delimiter used?  Please [edit] your question and improve it giving some example(s). A `4×5` or `5×4` cells or so could suffice.

Comment: `cmd` has a limitation of string length. With 1024 colums it is very likely, that you break this limitation. I would go for Powershell or some other "more advanced" scripting language.