# Batch script to read a tab separated text file line by line and extract one column to a new file

Tags: arrays, regex, batch-file, sed, substring

I have text files from exporting iTunes playlists that are tab separated arrays. They have 27 columns, but for simplicity, I'll just include four in the example:

```
Name    Artist  My Rating   Location
Pod1    Show1   0           E:\Podcasts\Show1\Episode99.m4a
Pod2    Show2   100         E:\Podcasts\Show2\Show2 Ep 101 - Subtitle.mp3
Pod3    Show2   60          E:\Podcasts\Show2\News 11-17-2014.aicc
```

And so on. I need to extract only the Location (which is always the last column) and place it in a new text file so it looks like this:

```
E:\Podcasts\Show1\Episode99.m4a
E:\Podcasts\Show2\Show2 Ep 101 - Subtitle.mp3
E:\Podcasts\Show2\News 11-17-2014.aicc
```

Here's the code I have so far towards that goal:

```
@ECHO OFF

type Podcasts.txt | findstr /v Grouping > Podcasts1.txt
del Podcasts.txt
rename Podcasts1.txt Podcasts.txt
```

While I've found some separate tutorials on modifying single lines and reading text files line by line, I've been having difficulty even modifying a single line the way I'd like, let alone merging the two principles. I figure this is probably a very quick answer I'm just not making the right search to find.

I found that it's possible to get the results I want in Notepad++ using the following REGEX:

```
Find: .+(E\:)
Replace: \1
```

So a way to do that line by line in a batch script would be helpful.

Bonus: I'm using the resulting file as a whitelist for deleting files that aren't on the playlist. If you have a link or can write a quick bit of code, that helps. Otherwise, I have ideas on how I plan to accomplish this that would require using a single folder.

**EDIT**: I've discovered that because some columns are blank, using this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-26,* delims=  " %%a in ("Podcasts.txt") do (
   echo %%q >> PodcastsTest.txt
)
```

Will sometimes hit the wrong column. I need something that can either search for the two characters "E:" and act from there or for the line search to go right to left in finding the first tab.

The quick and dirty method I just created that searches for a backslash (which currently only appears in Location) is the following:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=\" %%a in ("Podcasts.txt") do (
    echo E:\%%b >> PodcastsTest.txt
)
```

This is not a secure method since there's nothing stopping some other fields from having backslashes, but as a temporary solution, it works.

I discovered that [Linux SED is available for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm). Maybe there is a way to adapt the following Notepad++ REGEX search for it?

```
Find: .+(E\:)
Replace: \1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy a column in a .csv file to another using batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334682/copy-a-column-in-a-csv-file-to-another-using-batch) and others found with [\[batch-file\] csv copy column](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+csv+copy+column). Specify after `delims=` a horizontal tab character in the batch file and __FOR__ separates the field values by only the tab character instead of spaces and tabs as by default. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read all output help pages for details on this command.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new solution based on limitations of the source data and extra information added in the question, as well as acceptance to use another tool:

```
call jrepl ".*(E:.*)" "$1" /i /f "Podcasts.txt" /o "Podcasts2.txt"
```

The code above uses a native Windows batch script called `Jrepl.bat` (by dbenham)
jrepl.bat can be downloaded from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4otci4d4s8x5ni4/Jrepl.bat
and it can also be found here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Place it in the same folder as the batch file, or in a folder that is on the system path.

**Part 2**

The code below can then be used to generate a file which lists all the files in the current folder, that are not in the file generated from the jrepl code above.

You mention single folder - so that's what this handles and the file can be examined before using it to nuke the files.

**In fact this can be used with the original source file - if the filenames only appear once inside the file.**

```
@echo off
(
for %%a in (*.*) do (
   if /i not "%%~nxa"=="%~nx0" if /i not "%%~nxa"=="Podcasts2.txt" find /i "\%%~nxa" < "Podcasts2.txt" >nul || echo del "%%a"
)
)>delfiles.bat.txt"
```

**Below is a basic solution with data in all cells in the tab delimited file**

Without the file I can't be sure it has the right column but the technique should work.

Replace TAB with a literal tab character in an editor that doesn't convert TABs to spaces, like Notepad.

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-26,* delims=TAB" %%a in ("Podcasts.txt") do (
   echo %%b
)
pause
```

Comment: This is a good start that led to an insecure fix. I edited the question to incorporate my issues with it.

Comment: @LawrencePell  This answer has a new section

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pure batch solution that relies on the supposition that the desired location always begins with `E:\` (not case sensitive), and that string must not occur in any earlier columns:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
>"Podcasts.txt.new" (
  for /f "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%A in ("Podcasts.txt") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo !ln:*E:\=E:\!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

If you know that no location contains `!`, then you can simply enable delayed expansion at the top once, and remove the SETLOCAL and ENDLOCAL from the loop.

A regular expression is a great way to get the last column, regardless of content. A good regular expression utility for batch is [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a pure script based utility (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following JREPL one liner works well:

```
jrepl "[^\t]+$" $0 /jmatch /jbegln "skip=(ln==1)" /f "Podcasts.txt" /o "Podcasts.txt.new"
```

Here is another JREPL solution:

```
jrepl ".*\t" "" /a /jbegln "skip=(ln==1)" /f "Podcasts.txt" /o "Podcasts.txt.new"
```

Note - you must use CALL JREPL if you use either JREPL solution within a batch script.

That last regex can be adopted for use with sed:

```
sed "1d;s/.*\t//" "Podcasts.txt" >"Podcasts.txt.new"
```

Comment: EDIT - Fixed both solutions to skip the first line (the header line). Also fixed the JREPL solution to not print empty lines between the locations.

Comment: EDIT 2 - Added another JREPL option, as well as a sed solution that uses the same regex.

Answer (score 1):

with sed and several assumption

```
PathTocygwin/sed -e '\#.*[[:blank:]]\([A-Z]:/.*$# !d' -e 's//\1/' Podcasts.txt > Podcasts1.txt
del Podcasts.txt
rename Podcasts1.txt Podcasts.txt
```

assumption here
- path is using a mapping drive
- there is no previous path in 1 to 25 column
- keep only line that correspond to the pattern